# What is a good approach of to draw graphics with swing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint

I am a complete novice when it comes to any kind of graphics. So, I want to create a method in a class Creature that would be able to draw lines on a screen (turtle graphics style). I have no idea what would be a good way of doing this. I mean I could store all lines drawn by user in a container or whatever and every time the `repaint()` method is called I would redraw all lines but it looks bothersome. Or perhaps it's the best way and I am just being silly? As I said, I don't have any experience with this and everything is starting to look like black magic to me. I would appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Check out http://www.phy.ohiou.edu/~mousseau/phy303/scientific/all_33.html

Comment: You might find Processing (http://www.processing.org/) a useful alternative, depending on your project's aims.

Comment: Thank you both. It's a project for java lectures at university, so I can't use any alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for two common ways to do this:

1. Keep a List of objects to be painted and repaint them every time
2. Paint to a BufferedImage and just display the image

Answer (score 1):

Updating what to draw and actually drawing it should be separate, because you can't control when `repaint()` is called. You usually want to control how often the updating is done so it's always a good idea to separate. This also reduces the time it takes to draw so it increases performance as well.